# mysql query: select group_id but if any client_id in said group is = X then don't select

Tags: mysql

Sqlfiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df50/4

Basically, I have 3 tables: group, membership, client.

```
tbl.client = client_id (PK, AI), industry_id (FK), status
tbl.membership = membership_id (PK, AI), Client_id (FK to tbl.client), 
    group_id (FK to group), status
tbl.group = group_id (PK, AI), target_market_id (FK), geography_id (FK)
```

Basically, I want to select a group_id by joining all 3 tables where NONE of the clients can have a client.industry_id equal to a given input ($client_industry_id).

My query so far is:

```
"select g.group_id from `group` g join membership m on m.group_id=g.group_id ".
"join client c on c.client_id=m.client_id ".
"where g.status=1 and m.status=1 and c.status=1 and ".
"g.geography_id=$target_geography and ".
"g.target_market_id=$target_market ".
"c.industry_id <> $client_industry_id";
```

The problem with the query is that it will still select a group_id from group because ALL clients must not have a client_id = $client_industry_id in order to trip the <>.  I hope that makes sense?

Would I solve this problem via grouping?  If statement?

EDIT:

```
insert into client (email, industry_id, status) VALUES ('email1@gmail.com', '1', '1')
insert into client (email, industry_id, status) VALUES ('email2@gmail.com', '2', '1')
insert into client (email, industry_id, status) VALUES ('email3@gmail.com', '2', '1')

insert into membership (client_id, group_id) VALUES (1, 1)
insert into membership (client_id, group_id) VALUES (2, 1)
insert into membership (client_id, group_id) VALUES (3, 2)

insert into group (geography_id, target_market_id) VALUES (1, 1)
insert into group (geography_id, target_market_id) VALUES (1, 1)

#psuedo code
"select group_id from group join membership on group_id, join client on client_id where 
    all status=1 and group.geography_id=1 and group.target_market_id=1 and 
    NONE of the clients have client.industry_id=1

-- query should result in group_id=2
```

Comment: Explain with sample INPUT data and OUTPUT data

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly you want to select groups where client does not belong to the input industry. Correct me if I'm wrong.
Try moving the "c.industry_id <> $client_industry_id" in the join clause like "join client c on c.client_id=m.client_id and c.industry_id <> $client_industry_id"

Comment: updated the section.  @uchamp would I place that in the where clause?

Comment: try this
"select g.group_id from `group` g join membership m on m.group_id=g.group_id ".
"join client c on c.client_id=m.client_id and c.industry_id <> $client_industry_id".
"where g.status=1 and m.status=1 and c.status=1 and ".
"g.geography_id=$target_geography and ".
"g.target_market_id=$target_market ";

Comment: I must have accidentally skipped over that part when reading about joins... oops!  Thank you a ton!!

Comment: I'm glad these solutions worked for you. But I'm surprised too because they don't appear to fit the spec. I imagine you'd want to use "LEFT JOIN y ON y.id = x.id AND y.val = x.val WHERE y.id IS NULL"

Comment: @Strawberry you're actually right.  The below answer doesn't work; it did when I had a fixed dataset uploaded but after more testing it doesn't.  Can you explain your code a little more?

Comment: I'm suggesting an ***exclusion join***. Googling that should throw something up - it's a little late here so I'll leave it at that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You and @Strawberry are right, the previous code couldn't have worked. Sorry about that. And Here's a quick crack at what you might want to try instead:

```
select g.group_id from groupp g 
join membership m on m.group_id=g.group_id and m.status=1 //to consider check on status
join client c on c.client_id=m.client_id and c.status=1 //to consider check on status
where g.group_id not in (select mm.group_id from membership mm join client cc on mm.client_id=cc.client_id and cc.industry_id = $client_industry_id) and //to exclude groups with clients that have industry
g.status=1 and
g.geography_id=$target_geography and
g.target_market_id=$target_market;
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work.  I had a bad dataset in place.  It still shows groups that have clients in them with c.industry_id=XXX